# How to Install extensions into Magento version 2.1.7 from Magento Connect?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, extensions, plugin, magento-connect

I am using Magento 2.1.7. I am trying to install some extension from Magento Connect. But i am not able to do it. 
Can anyone tell me the correct way to install an extension into my Magento version 2.1.7 from Magento Connect ?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download the extension

Step 2: Unzip the files

Step 3: Upload it to your Magento root directory

Step 4: Enter the following at the command line:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Step 5: Clear Cache in the command line using

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Step 6: Redeploy your theme using

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

if your site uses multiple languages you will need to specify them on the previous command like so

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB
```

Comment: Hi @Dava ! Thanks for your answer. But the steps you have written are good to install extensions from Magento MarketPlace. But I was looking for some ways by which i can install extensions from Magento Connect  into my Magento Version 2.1.7.   Please reffer this  [link](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/responsive-custom-menu.html) if you want to have more clarification on what i am asking ?       https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/responsive-custom-menu.html

Comment: Download from https://web-experiment.info/webandpeople-custom-menu-extension and follow steps in answer

Comment: Hi @Dava_Gordon ! i am using Magento version 2.1.7. The extension you suggested i have installed it , but there was no change. is there any other extensions for Responsive menu available for magento 2.1.7 ?

Comment: If you have installed and run setup upgrade and cleared you cache then I'd look at the layout file and see if it's referenced in template if not google my name and add git after should bring up my megamenu extension